# What is the connection between the Blood Series?

Tags: blood+, blood-c

I watched *Blood: The Last Vampire* a while back and I know there are other series like *Blood+*, *Blood-C* and *Blood-C: The Last Dark* and a manga called *Blood*.

From what I read, in all of the series, the main character is a girl named Saya, and from what I took from the Movie *Blood: The Last Vampire*, Saya is a vampire herself.

I am wondering if the different Blood series have any sort of connection to each other through Saya or any other connection.

Comment: *Blood*, *Blood+*, and *Blood C* are all parallel universes from one another, like the *Ghost in the Shell* movies and TV series. *Blood-C: The Last Dark*, acts as a sequel to the *Blood-C* series.

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/is-blood-c-set-in-the-same-world-as-blood